# How to overcome the Permgen Space Exception Without restarting the Server.., Can any one help me

Tags: java, sql

How to overcome the Permgen Space Exception Without restarting the Server.., Can any one help me....?

Comment: Any effort from your side ??? And try to trace the problem for permgen. Don't keep increase the memory.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not. Please go through below article this will provide a better idea about the same

[java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html)

[difference-between-stack-and-heap-java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/01/difference-between-stack-and-heap-java.html)

[garbage-collection-in-java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)